# Manhwa where the MC wants to be a paladin but got scammed into a villain class

Tags: story-identification, manga

What manhwa is where the main character wants to be a paladin originally but got scammed by the NPC to become a villain class. His favor for everyone dropped and he is hated but super over-powered class, something like a 'bandit cult' or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: I don't know the name, but I think it was inspired by Warcraft which came out between late 90s and early 2000s.